# for loop not finishing

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am a programming newbie trying to learn python.

I am trying to backup cryptocurrency data to my own database for back-testing later.
This is my currently written code.

```py
    import pandas
    from pandas.io.sql import to_sql
    import sqlite3
    import pybithumb
    import pickle
    
    print("\nOpening DB and saved_tickers...")
    con= sqlite3.connect("E:\pythonDB\DB_fetch_1m.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    with open ("saved_tickers.lst", "rb") as fp:
        saved_tickers = pickle.load(fp)
    
    for ticker in saved_tickers:
        # print("\n" + str('## ') + ticker + str(' ##'))
        # print("Creating new database tables if needed...")
        cur.execute(f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {ticker} (time TIMESTAMP PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, open, high, low, close, volume)")
        # print("Fetching latest data from Bithumb.")
        data = pybithumb.get_candlestick(ticker, "KRW", "1m")   
        # print("Saving and Processing DB...")
        data.to_sql(str(ticker) + "_tmp", con, if_exists='replace')
        table = ticker
        table_tmp = ticker+"_tmp"
        cur.execute(f"INSERT OR IGNORE INTO {table} SELECT * FROM {table_tmp}")
```

saved_tickers.lst contains my selection of cryptocurrency. Right now, if I

```
print(saved_tickers)
```

I get

```py
['XRP', 'LTC', 'ETC', 'BTC', 'ETH']
```

when I run this code, the code :

- fetches cryptocurrency data from saved_tickers list one by one,
- checks if there is a table by its name and makes it if there isn't one in db file.

At this point, the column 'time' is set to Primary key so that no duplicate info of given time is in the table.

It also saves the same data to 'ticker'_tmp table.
It then inserts 'ticker'_tmp data to 'ticker' (so that table 'ticker' has no duplicates)
The code goes well and do what it's been intended to do but the last item in the list is always having problems.
It checks and creates table named 'ticker' if there isn't any.
It then makes and replaces the newly fetched data to table 'ticker'_tmp.
But it never inserts 'ticker'_tmp data to 'ticker' table.
(not running INSERT OR IGNORE INTO {table} SELECT * FROM {table_tmp})

And I do not know why.
I've tried double checking the ticker name. Changed the saved_list few times
And every single time, the last of the list is having problems.

Please, any advice is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Missing `commit` ?

Comment: thanks you very much!!! I guess I have missed some parts reading and studying.
adding con.commit() after for loop solved it! thanks.